# Home Navigation Up not returning to Caller Activity.

Tags: android, email

Dear enthusiastic committed android developers

I m  developing android application , in which I open any other application like Gmail for sending Email.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);



        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");

        try {
            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished sending email.", "");
        }
        catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(EmailSendingActivity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Gmail composer activity gets opened from where i can send email to intended recipient.

Now if I press back key on composer activity , it takes me back to my application. (right navigation step for my app).

But If I press home up navigation key at to top left, it takes me to the default activity of Gmail Application. instead I want to go navigation up to my application.

Is it technically feasible in android ?

Thanks

Comment: You probably cannot handle navigation key of another application

Comment: hmm.. but If I can't handle navigation key of another application .. this can enable user to leave my application after pressing navigation key.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in your activity onCreate.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

and in your application manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".yourActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ParentActivity" >
</activity>
```

where parent activity is activity where you want to go after clicking home up Navigation.

Comment: Thanks for answering but this won't solve this issue .. since I don't have to source code of other application in which I have to write this code.